# sed command 'invalid command' problem in macOS

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sed

I got some hint that MacOs has different command when using 'sed'.

The original command I have to do was like:

```
sed -n  '1~36p' /filename
```

What I got is changing

```
sed [-an] command [file...]
```

into

```
sed [-an] [-e command] [-f command_file] [file...]
```

so I changed my command as

```
sed -n -e '1~36p' -f /filename
```

But it came out with different error like

> sed: 1: "1~36p
> ": invalid command code ~

Did I got wrong command? I want to know how to change properly for Mac.

Comment: Check your file for unprintable and invisible characters. `sed: 1: "1~36p ":` - there is a space after `p` in error message.

Comment: `~` is a GNU `sed` extension and is not available with the default `sed` that comes with macOS. Install GNU `sed` with, e.g., [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) if you absolutely need this.

Comment: `first~step` form for selecting lines is a GNU extension. You need GNU `sed` (or use `awk`).

Comment: Also, the argument of `-f` option is a file that contains sed commands to be run. It is not the input file to be processed.

Comment: Also, the `-e` optional unless you're supplying more than one command (e.g. `sed -e '1-3 d' -e 's/this/that/' /filename`), or supplying arguments in a nonstandard order, or something like that. In other words, the `-e` and `-f` are both irrelevant here. The only problem is that `~` is not supported.

Comment: You can install **GNU sed** on **macOS** with **homebrew**. It would be `brew install gnu-sed` and you then invoke it using `gsed`.

Comment: Or, if you have **docker** installed, you could run `docker run -it debian:latest sed ...`

Answer (score 2):

The `~` is a GNU extension to sed.  You can use `sed -n '1~36p'` on macOS, but you'll have to use a different command to get the same effect.  The easiest way is to use `awk`:
`awk 'NR % 36 == 1' /filename`